# create a rails helpers bound to a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

Is it possible to have a helper method just like rolify on other tables? rolify has helpers: .has_role?, add_role...

I want to create exactly this helpers for another table (which is is not role table).

Thanks

Comment: yes you can create .. just add method in that model

Comment: That is what I did actually and was wondering if there was a different way. Now I got it. Thanks.